# Android как получить путь External

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь создать папку во внешнем хранилище и потом получить путь к нему в виде переменной String. В результате папка не создается хотя в манифесте доступ прописан.

```
            // получаем путь к External
            File FPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            FPath = new File(FPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Word");
            FPath.mkdir();
            // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу

            String filePath = 
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Word";
```

Файл манифеста

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.lesson5">

            <application
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
              android:supportsRtl="true"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
             <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
          </activity>
          </application>
        <uses-permission 
         android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission 
         android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

           </manifest>
```

Comment: new File("FPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Word"").mkdirs(); пробовали?

Comment: Привидите код манифестиа

Comment: В манифете вроде все ОК

Comment: mkdirs пробовали?

Comment: я просто не очень понял как это сделать ?

Comment: я ответ дал - это создание пустой папки

Comment: Решение **сильно** зависит от версии Android, так что показывайте свой манифест с `minSdk` и `targetSdk` (ну или gradle - если это объявлено там)

Answer (score 0):

```
success = (new File("../potentially/long/pathname/without/all/dirs")).mkdirs();
if (!success) {
// Directory creation failed
}
```